# Rest endpoint hangs on Windows only. Other endpoints work

Tags: rest, spring-boot, wildfly

So... this is a really weird issue I am having a lot of trouble figuring out.

I deployed an app with Wildfly. It's a spring boot java aplication with rest endpoints.

The app works fine when accessed with Ubuntu+chrome, but in Windows+chrome+firefox (tested in 4 different machines) there is a particular endpoint that "hangs". It stays in PENDING status when looking at the chrome developer console. Accessing the end-point directly using the browser's address bar also hangs with no response.

The endpoint in question is **/auth**

Here is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${base.url}")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/auth")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void validateAuthentication() {
        // nothing
    }

    @GetMapping("/now")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public SimpleDateOutput fetchCurrentDate() {
        return SimpleDateOutput.of(new Date());
    }
}
```

Also, the "/now" endpoint WORKS.

We have another different server running with an **embedded tomcat**, and that one works fine in both OSs.

So, I am really at a loss here. Has anyone seen such weird behavior?

Comment: So where is that "hanging" endpoint's code?

Comment: @Antoniossss Of course! Sorry! It's the /auth.

Comment: What will happen if you `HttpStatus.OK` ?

Comment: It would return 200 instead of 204.

Comment: Thank you captain obvious - will it hang?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question (English is not my first language). I am going to try it and report here.

Comment: @Antoniossss is worked. Changing the status to OK did it. If you would be so kind as to post an answer, I would gladly accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to `HttpStatus.OK`, maybe it will help.